# Make a ListView visible when the layout is set to have black background

Tags: android, xml

I have a simple `activity` with a `relative layout`, `ListView`, and a `TextView`
I want to make my app have black background and white text, but when I set the background of `Layout` and `TextView` to black, the `ListView` isn't visible...

How can i overcome this problem. I want background to be black, but still have the `ListView` visible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtOut"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/songListView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtIn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This was hard to explain, so I apologize for that, although i tried my best.

Comment: post your xml and more to explain. and also listview item xml

Comment: @ZakiPathan I did that

Comment: you have TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" match parent so how listview shows here. change TextView height to wrap_content

Comment: if this doesn't help please post your listview item xml

Comment: check my answer below @Eddie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting everything to black, choose a dark theme.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtOut"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/songListView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtIn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

try this hope it helps

Comment: The `RelativeLayout` is also set to black.

Comment: @Eddie yes. If this doesn't work please provide screenshot what you are getting and also provide listview item layout xml